# Сообщение удалено

Tags: дефект

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не красиво получается. Такой вывод информации об удалённом вопросе корректный для  SO?

Увидел, что сообщение удалено — обновил страницу.

Comment: Эм.. Но редактирование удалённых возможно же...

Comment: А, у тебя ещё репутации мало...

Comment: @Qwertiy и ромбика нет к тому же.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, для ответов ромб не нужен: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/486387/revisions. Вроде с вопросами что-то посложнее, не помню точно.